# Updating geometry field automatically from East and North fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geometry, fields-attributes, update, xy

I have a layer that contains a number of fields, two of which are `"East"` and `"North"`.

I would like to be able to set up the layer so I fill out the attribute form including entering the east and north, and the geometry field is calculated on save.

I would also like it to update the geometry field on an edit of the east or north field.

I did find calculated fields and can manually get it to update, but can't figure out how to *"define"* this so it automatically happens.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume there is a point layer called *'random_points_test'* with several features in it, see image below.

[image: input]

Hereupon I am suggesting two cases, because there is a bridge between geometry and attribute table, and one can have an impact on another as well as vice versa.

In both cases Check the `Properties > Attribute Form > Defaults` and tick the `Apply default value on update`, see image below.

### Case 1 : when a change in the attribute table leads to a change of the geometry

The solution was described here: [Updating feature geometry from attribute fields in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285634/qgis-update-feature-geometry-from-attribute-fields).

[image: window1]

***before :***
[image: case1_before]

***after :***
[image: case1_after]

### Case 2 : when a change of the geometry leads to a change in the attribute table

[image: window2]

***before :***
[image: case2_before]

***after :***
[image: case2_after]

---

**References:**

- [Updating feature geometry from attribute fields in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285634/qgis-update-feature-geometry-from-attribute-fields)
- [Editing feature geometry in action using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340072/editing-feature-geometry-in-action-using-pyqgis)
- [How to digitize building footprints with orthogonal edges?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141521/how-to-digitize-building-footprints-with-orthogonal-edges)
- [Updating an existing field with field calculator in QGIS modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388462/updating-an-existing-field-with-field-calculator-in-qgis-modeler)

Comment: I feel like this does the opposite of what I want. Does this not take the centroid coordinates of the geometry (in this case the point coordinates), and assign them to the fields "East", and "North"? I actually want to do the opposite. Something like 
updating the geometry feild to = geom_to_wkt(make_point("East", "North")) any time there is an add or edit action?